# Wrong or missing parameter QgsProcessingParameterFile QGIS 3.4 Python plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I'm making a script that can be called by the `processing.execAlgorithmDialog` function. For one of the parameters, I want to use the `QgsProcessingParameterFile` class for selecting a .csv file.

I tried the following:

```
class T4_Visualiseer_Networks_Resultaat(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    PrmOutputFile = 'Networks result'

    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterFile(
            name=self.PrmOutputFile,
            description="Networks resultaat",
            extension="csv(*.csv)"
        )
    )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # Some code to do after clicking ok
```

When I select a .csv file in a folder and press OK to begin the script, I get the message ***Wrong or missing parameter value: Networks resultaat*** (see picture below).

[image]

I already tried the following:

- Replace / by \
- Add `behavior=0` to make sure a file is selected (this was already the case because the default value for behavior is 0)
- Rename the .csv file

None of the above actions fixed the problem of getting this message and I can't find any other solutions on the internet.

Do you have any idea what the problem can be or how I can fix it?

Comment: Does changing "CSV(*.CSV)" to "CSV (*.CSV)" help? (I.e. adding the space)

Comment: @ndawson Unfortunately this doesn't solve it

Answer (score 4):

In the [code source](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/processing/qgsprocessingparameters.h) you can read

`The extension argument allows for specifying a file extension associated with the parameter (e.g. "html"). 
Use fileFilter for a more flexible approach which allows for multiple file extensions. Only one of extension or fileFilter should be specified, if both are specified then fileFilter takes precedence.`

Hence, you have to put the extension: `"csv"`, `"csv(*.csv)"` is valid for the parameter `fileFilter`.